# Run code in block only when certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here I want to show you a demo code:

```
if ENV["PRODUCTION"]
  user.apply_discount!
  product.update!
else
 VCR.use_cassette(vcr_cassette) do
    user.apply_discount!
    product.update!
 end
end
```

So basically **two times** I have there the same code:

```
   user.apply_discount!
   product.update!
```

**How can I prevent this duplication of code?** How would you do it?
I was thinking of putting the code inside a Block and then either call it directly or in the block. Here's an example:

```
actions =  Proc.new do
  user.apply_discount!
  product.update!
end

if ENV["PRODUCTION"]
  actions.call
else
 VCR.use_cassette(vcr_cassette) do
    actions.call
 end
end
```

**Do you have another idea? Better solution?** Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version is explicit and readable.

The only thing I'd do is moving it to a general method:

```
def do_env_specific_stuff(stuff)
  ENV('PRODUCTION') ? stuff.call : VCR.use_cassette(vcr_cassette) { stuff.call }
end
```

Then:

```
stuff = proc do
  user.apply_discount!
  product.update!
end

do_env_specific_stuff(stuff)
```

Comment: This is cool. But `ENV('PRODUCTION')` is accessible within the method so do we need to pass it as an argument?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn good call. No need to pass everywhere accessible variable :)

Answer (score 2):

Andrey's answer is excellent and should be accepted.

But just want to point out that you can convert a proc to a block instead of calling a proc in a block...

```
 VCR.use_cassette(vcr_cassette, &actions)
```

I think the explicit call is better, but just wanted to point out an alternative technique.